# Why is SCSS complaining when I use `list.nth` when `stylelint-scss` is telling me to?

Tags: css, webpack, sass, sass-loader, stylelint

I have a bit of a situation here.

I'm using SCSS in a React app using `sass-loader` and I lint my SCSS/CSS using `stylelint` and the extension for it `stylelint-scss`.

I borrowed some code from here: https://medium.com/dev-channel/using-sass-to-automatically-pick-text-colors-4ba7645d2796 and I'm trying to use it in my files. Here's how I have it:

```
@function luminance($color) {
  $red: nth(linear-channel-values(), red($color) + 1);
  $green: nth(linear-channel-values(), green($color) + 1);
  $blue: nth(linear-channel-values(), blue($color) + 1);

  @return 0.2126 * $red + 0.7152 * $green + 0.0722 * $blue;
}
```

So then `stylelint-scss` complains to me:

```
WARNING in
src/assets/scss/helpers.scss
 282:9   ✖  Expected list.nth instead of nth        scss/no-global-function-names
 282:38  ✖  Expected color.red instead of red       scss/no-global-function-names
 283:11  ✖  Expected list.nth instead of nth        scss/no-global-function-names
 283:40  ✖  Expected color.green instead of green   scss/no-global-function-names
 284:10  ✖  Expected list.nth instead of nth        scss/no-global-function-names
 284:39  ✖  Expected color.blue instead of blue     scss/no-global-function-names
```

Ok, so I change my `nth` function calls to `list.nth`... and then I get another complaint:

```
@use "sass:color";
@use "sass:list";

@function luminance($color) {
  $red: list.nth(linear-channel-values(), color.red($color) + 1);
  $green: list.nth(linear-channel-values(), color.green($color) + 1);
  $blue: list.nth(linear-channel-values(), color.blue($color) + 1);

  @return 0.2126 * $red + 0.7152 * $green + 0.0722 * $blue;
}
```

```
ERROR in ./src/assets/scss/index.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--6-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader!./src/assets/scss/index.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Invalid CSS after "  $red: list": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ".nth(linear-channel"
        on line 282 of src/assets/scss/helpers.scss
        from line 7 of /Users/ogabay/Projects/mercury/app/pennypal/src/assets/scss/index.scss
>>   $red: list.nth(linear-channel-values(), color.red($color) + 1);

   ------------^

 @ ./src/assets/scss/index.scss 2:26-262 43:4-64:5 46:18-254
 @ ./src/index.jsx
```

Is the issue here with `stylelint-scss` or `sass-loader`?

Comment: Stylelint is probably assuming you are using modular SCSS when you aren't, based on the last error.